# Exporting a Composable as Bitmap (or png) in Compose Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-multiplatform

I have a project where I dynamically generate a tree as a composable which I can edit.

Now I wanted to add a feature, where I can export this tree as a bitmap (another format will likely do the job as well)

I've seen lots of implementations where they use

```
Bitmap.createBitmap()
```

from the library `android.graphics.Bitmap` which takes a view from the composable

But with the standard Compose Multiplatform Library Stack this lib is not there, and I don't feel like installing it for this one thing

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Is the problem still unresolved?